# Git: --force-with-lease and multiple pushurls

Tags: git

I have a git repo with remote `origin` mirrored on 3 hosts.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:username/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:username/repo.git (push)
origin  git@gitlab.com:username/repo.git (push)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git (push)
```

Everything, everywhere is at commit **A**.

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
A

$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
A
```

I author commit **B** and push it. Now everyone's at commit **B**.

```
$ git push origin master
To github.com:username/repo.git
   A...B             master -> master
To gitlab.com:username/repo.git
   A...B             master -> master
To bitbucket.org:username/repo.git
   A...B             master -> master

$ git rev-parse HEAD
B

$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
B
```

Now I notice a mistake in that last commit, so I fix it and ammend the commit. This puts me out of sync with the remote(s).

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
C

$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
B
```

I like to avoid blindly `--force` pushing, so I use `--force-with-lease`, but this fails in an interesting way.

```
$ git push --force-with-lease origin master
To github.com:username/repo.git
 + B...C             master -> master (forced update)
To gitlab.com:username/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (stale info)
To bitbucket.org:username/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (stale info)
```

The problem is, `--force-with-lease` will only consider the push safe if the remote ref is at the same commit as last time I communicated with it, and my local records the sha1 of that commit in `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master`. As soon as the first mirror (GitHub) is updated, git updates my local's remote ref to commit **C**, causing the push attempts to GitLab and Bitbucket to fail, since we're now expecting them to be at commit **C**.

I want to figure this out, so first I force the GitHub mirror back to commit **B**.

```
$ git push origin +B:refs/heads/master
To github.com:username/repo.git
 + C...B             B -> master (forced update)
Everything up-to-date
Everything up-to-date
```

Now I need to be more specific about which commit I expect the remotes to be at for the push. The documentation says you can specify exactly which ref to update, and what commit you expect it to currently be at with `--force-with-lease=<refname>:<expect>`, so I try that.

```
$ git push --force-with-lease=origin/master:B origin master
To github.com:username/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
To gitlab.com:username/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
To bitbucket.org:username/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. Maybe I've got the `<refname>` wrong? I feel I'm so close. What am I missing?

Comment: An interesting test to try: `git push --force-with-lease=$(git rev-parse origin/master):B origin master` (i.e., raw commit ID rather than name).  I'm not sure when Git does the name to ID translation for this particular edge case.

Comment: @torek It was worth a shot, but no dice. It did the same thing (all pushes rejected as "non-fast-forward").

Comment: Interesting. I'm just guessing (the code is pretty twisty) but I suspect the force-with-lease option winds up being forgotten somewhere during the multiple URLs. I bet it works much better if you just have one remote for each URL.

Comment: @torek I'm starting to suspect that as well. It's nice being able to push to all three with a single command, but maybe there's a way to do so with multiple remotes defined as well.

Comment: @ivan were you able to test out my answer and see if it works for you or I've messed something up? Thanks!

Comment: @HaralanDobrev I just tested it and it worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Very interesting question! I've tried it out and successfully reproduced what you are describing with Git 2.11.0 in these test repos:

- https://github.com/hkdobrev/git-test
- https://github.com/hkdobrev/git-test2

I was able to successfully push with `--force-with-lease` to both remote URLs by using the following form:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin +master
```

Notice the `+` sign before the branch name. Here is the output:

```
$ git push --force-with-lease origin +master
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 232 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To github.com:hkdobrev/git-test.git
 + 099b95f...08c7548 master -> master (forced update)
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 232 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To github.com:hkdobrev/git-test2.git
 + 099b95f...08c7548 master -> master (forced update)
```

From the `git-push (1)` man page:

> Note that `--force` applies to all the refs that are pushed, hence using it with `push.default` set to matching or with multiple push destinations
>              configured with `remote.*.push` may overwrite refs other than the current branch (including local refs that are strictly behind their remote
>              counterpart). To force a push to only one branch, use a `+` in front of the refspec to push (e.g `git push origin +master` to force a push to the `master`
>              branch). See the `<refspec>...`  section above for details.

Comment: As I pointed out in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693153/git-force-with-lease-and-multiple-pushurls/65697662#65697662), I think that this leads basically to a normal force push.

Answer (score 3):

What I have come up with is

```sh
git push --force-with-lease=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{u} | sed 's![^/]*/!!'`:@{u}
```

where

- `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{u} | sed 's![^/]*/!!'` gets the remote branch name (without the remote name)
- `@{u}` is the commit where we expect the remote branch to be

I also tried out the `+` spec as [suggested by Haralan Dobrev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693153/git-force-with-lease-and-multiple-pushurls/41153073#41153073) but was able to override changes using that. Therefore, **I think that the `+` spec should *not* be used here** because it [equals a normal force push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203).

Comment: If I remember correctly, when I have tried this out on Git 2.11.0, the `+` modifier was working as expected and the lease option was respected.

Comment: I was able to make it work with the branch name and the remote name, more readable IMO:
`$ git push --force-with-lease="master:origin/master" "origin" "master"`